# What is "ptymonitor" seen in the Linux system logs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I see "kernel: ptymonitor[8742]: segfault at" in the var logs ... what does "ptymonitor" mean?
I don't see any online resources to provide an answer.

Comment: Wow Google actually has a hard time with this one. Still belongs on serverfault. Off it goes then.

Answer (score 0):

ptyMonitor = Pseudo Terminal Monitor, a process that monitors access to your pTTY and logs what means of validation/access or some other information that happens at those endpoints. A "SegFault" is a segmentation fault, something in memory broke due to an unexpected behavior or data input, check why that process "broke" it may give you some insightful information, now that process won't stop nothing critical but it is always good to have a good healthy system.

Hope this may help you.

Peace!